# Unable to open file by a relative path in FORTRAN 77

Tags: file, fortran, fortran77

I wrote FORTRAN 77 code which opens (creates) a file and writes some information into it. Everything works great if I open the file like

```
INTEGER U
U=1
OPEN(U, FILE='data.txt')
```

But if I want the file to be created in a different dir specifying a relative path (OS Ubuntu)

```
INTEGER U
U=1
OPEN(U, FILE='../output_files/data.txt')
```

my gfortran compiler gives me the following error:

```
OPEN(U,FILE='../output_files/data.txt')
           1
Error: Invalid value for FILE specification at (1)
```

Seems like absolute path is working in my case. I have spent some time doing some research on the Internet and found that every manual I looked into said that relative path should work as well. That's important for me. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

**Update**

The real code I was using is

```
INTEGER U
U=1
OPEN(U, FILE='output_files/energies_and_first_interaction_coordinates_mum.txt')
```

and the error is

```
  OPEN(U,FILE='output_files/energies_and_first_interaction_coordinates_mum.txt')
         1
  Error: Invalid value for FILE specification at (1)
```

Comment: Please show us a complete compilable example ([mcve]) for us to look at.  As this isn't a complete example, I'll have to guess at things to check: are you sure the line is not too long?

Comment: The code as presented it fine. As @francescalus suggests, this is almost certainly an indication that the actual line of code in question extends beyond the 72 character limit.

Comment: Seems like the name is too long. I am new to Fortran, so I didn't know the case, thank you.

Comment: @Sentenza : Please update the question with the actual code so it can be of use to others. And, once that's done, you can put your "SOLVED" edit as an answer (it is acceptable to answer your own questions here), and accept it as the answer. That way people browsing the site will see that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to francescalus and L. Scott Johnson.The problem was that the command to open file was expanded beyond 72 position on the line (the name of my file was to long).