# How to read a file from a relative path in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, relative-path

Let's say I have my directory set up like this (as an example):

- Main

  - Scripts

    - read.f95
  - Files

    - file.txt

How would I go about using relative path to read in file.txt in my read.f95 file?

I tried using relative path as

`open(10, file='./Files/file.txt')` and

`open(10, file='../Files/file.txt')`

but I am getting a path error on both ways. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184799/unable-to-open-file-by-a-relative-path-in-fortran-77) question, but the issue there was a too long filename, which is not what I am asking about.

Comment: Rather than where the source file lives, where are you running the compiled program?

Comment: I'm not sure, where can I check this?

Comment: Where is your compiled executable and where (which path) do you run it from?

Comment: I'm compiling and running from within Plato

Comment: Then your current working directory (i.e. the path where you relative path statement starts from) is most likely some path set by Plato and therefore not what you are actually thinking it is -> your relative path is wrong.

You can check the working directory using 'getcwd':
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETCWD.html

Comment: To rule out other issues, you can use the _full_ path of the input file (rather than relative). Hardcoded relative paths in source files won't make your life easy (not that hardcoded full paths are ideal).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have structure like this:

```
.
|-- code
|   |-- relative
|   `-- relative.F90
`-- data
    `-- data.dat
```

and you want to run your code from the directory that contains both: `code` and `data`. In that case, you can always concatenate location of your current directory and the location of data:

```
program relative

   implicit none 

   real :: x, y

   character (len=255) :: cwd
   call getcwd(cwd)

   open (10, file = trim(cwd)//'/data/data.dat', status = 'old')
   read (10, *) x, y
   close(10)
   write(*,  *) x, y

end program
```

while data file: `data.dat` looks following way

```
0.1 0.2
```

Once you run it, you will get what you want:

```
> ./code/relative
  0.100000001      0.200000003
```

However, you have to be extra careful with this approach. It will work only in certain locations - it will work as long as `data/data.dat` is present. It might be useful in case you submit jobs into batch. Let's say you have no idea where you code will end up (in terms of explicit location). In that case, you can't hardcode it - it makes no sense. So, you have two choices: either you can use some wrapper script and pass location into your code via arguments, or, you can make sure that directory structure looks like you want and you know that everything is in place. In that case, using `getcwd` makes perfect sense.